# Form Validation - Server Side vs Client Side

Tags: joomla-3.4, jform, validations

Just got confused by seeing both type of validations in Joomla.  So far my understanding of these 2 is as below

**Client Side Validation**

Done via jQuery/Javascript on the client browser

**Server Side Validation**

Done at server after the page got submitted

Trying to understand how server side validation works with a simple mandatory field example.

The XML form field as below

```
<field name="note_name" 
  type="text" 
  label="Note Name" 
  required="true" />
```

In the default.php I have the below code

```
//JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
<form .... class="form-vertical" ...>
echo $this->form->renderField('note_name');
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

In the above code I have not included any client-side validation code and I was thinking the page will get submit and the server will do the validation.  But the page doesn't get submit and it simply shows a nice popup near to the field asking to 'Please input this field'.

What am I missing here? Why the client validation is getting triggered even though I haven't included any client side validation code?

Answer (score 1):

It is automatic validation by your browser because `required` attributed is set on the input field. Here is a list of browsers that support this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

Comment: More info on the HTML5 `required` form attribute: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute